# The send or update operation could not be performed because the change key passed in the request does not match the current change key for the item

Tags: java, office365, exchangewebservices

I am creating and sending mails (set up on office 365) using exchange server. I am using EWS server in java to send mails. From a week ago, I am getting the below issue on Windows machines when sending mails. I have also tried adding a delay of 1 second after adding the attachments. Still, I am facing this problem. The issue has also become very frequent.

ERROR_IRRESOLVABLE_CONFLICT -

The send or update operation could not be performed because the change key passed in the request does not match the current change key for the item., Cannot submit message.SaveStatus: IrresolvableConflict

Can someone please advise what can be done to avoid this error?

Comment: Have you tried to a GetItem (load in the Managed API) to load the latest change key before using Send. It sounds like another process could be modifying the Message in the intrem

Comment: Thank you for this reply but I am still facing the same issue. I monitored this case for around a few weeks but still the issue persists.

Comment: What have you tried to fix the issue eg GetItem etc

Comment: I used getItem before sending the item and also I retried sending the item every second for 10 seconds on getting this error. But even after this, I got this issue.